# Looking for a option spinner/option wheel like control in android

Tags: android, user-interface, spinner

Looking for a control that allows to select one text value at a time for android with 2 arrows on each side. Not sure what the control is called but here is an example image:

[image]

Comment: I've never seen a control like it.  You might just have to create it yourself.

Comment: I seen it in a number of places however don't think I've seen it in android. If I get no answers I will just make it myself. I just wanted to avoid to reinvent the wheel(sorry for the pun) if I didn't have too.

Comment: I should have qualified my answer with "for android".  I too have seen it elsewhere.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created my own, which works great for me. The Galley control helped a lot. Feel free to point out any issues though.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import nz.co.nuffie.android.crichq.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ScrollWheelControl extends LinearLayout{
    private final ArrayList<String> textList = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayAdapter optionAdapter = null;
    private AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener itemSelectedListener = null;

    public ScrollWheelControl(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollWheelControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context);
    }

    public ScrollWheelControl(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView(context);
    }

    public void initView(Context context) {
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.scroll_wheel_control, this);

        optionAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, textList )
        {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
                if(v instanceof TextView){//Just in case.
                    TextView txt = (TextView)v;
                    Gallery.LayoutParams glp = new Gallery.LayoutParams(Gallery.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, Gallery.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                    txt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    txt.setLayoutParams(glp);
                }
                return v;
            }
        };


        optionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        final Gallery g = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gOptionSelect);
        g.setAdapter(optionAdapter);

        final Button btnLeft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLeft);
        final Button btnRight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRight);
        g.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position >= textList.size()-1){
                    btnRight.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                }else
                    btnRight.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                if(position == 0){
                    btnLeft.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                }else
                    btnLeft.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

                if(itemSelectedListener != null){
                    itemSelectedListener.onItemSelected(list,view,position,id);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
        btnLeft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                g.onFling(null, null, 2000, 0);
            }
        });
        btnRight.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                g.onFling(null, null, -2000, 0);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setOnItemListener(AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener setItemSelectedListener){
        itemSelectedListener = setItemSelectedListener;
    }

    public void addTextItems(List<String> list){
        textList.addAll(list);
        if(optionAdapter != null){
            optionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLeft"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="\u003C"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:minWidth="15dp"
            />

    <Gallery
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/gOptionSelect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:spacing="0dp">
    </Gallery>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRight"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="\u003E" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        android:shadowDx="1"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:minWidth="15dp"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is for date, I would probably advise you to use the DatePicker which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yS9XY.png). Else if it's for time then probably you may want something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5GZv.png).

However if you are looking for something like a NumberPicker, it's seems to be only available API 11 and up. Therefore if you want, you may need to customize your own.

Comment: None of those. Its just for text only. There is no such control in Android but there might be a library/sample text out there. I probably will need to make it.

Comment: Hmm.. there is also a spinner that's just like a dropdown list which enables one selection each time but I guess you should make your own as the example image that you gave does look better.

Comment: In most cases yes I would use that but not in this one. I'm already in a AlertDialog and creating another popup on top will look messy. Also I'll just have just 2 or 3 options in each spinner control and a few of these spinners, don't want a popup for each one. But thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey i think just take a look at [this](http://android-devblog.blogspot.in/2010/05/wheel-ui-contol.html) wheel control.. The custom control created by third party person. He also given other details in his blog.. which you can modify it if you want..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did have a look, it was what I wanted but would be a lot of work converting it to horizontal.